# Scraping links with selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I was working to scrape links to articles on a website. But normally when site was loaded it list only 5 articles then it requires to click load more button to display more articles list. 
Html source has only links to first five articles.

I used selenium python to automate clicking load more button to completely load webpage with all article listings.

Question is now how can i extract links to all those articles.

After loading site completely with selenium i tried to get html source with driver.page_source and printed it but still it has only link to first 5 articles.

I want to get links to all those articles that were loaded in webpage after clicking load more button.

Please someone help to provide solution.

Comment: Can you provide a URL?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the links take some time to show up and your code is doing `driver.source_code` before the source code is updated. You can select the links with Selenium after an explicit wait so that you can make sure that the links that are dinamically added to the web page are fully loaded. It is difficult to boil down exactly what you need without a link to your source, but (in Python) it should be something similar to:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def condition(driver):
    """If the selector defined in the function retrieves 10 or more results, return the results.
    Else, return None.
    """
    selector = 'a.my_class' # Selects all <a> tags with the class "my_class" 
    els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
    if len(els) >= 10:
        return els

# Making an assignment only when the condition returns a truthy value when called (waiting until 2 min):
links_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=120).until(condition)
# Getting the href attribute of the links 
links_href = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links_elements]
```

In this code, you are:

- Constantly looking for the elements you want until there are 10 or more of them. You can do this by CSS Selector (as in the example), XPath or [other method](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/#element-selection-strategies). This gives you a list of Selenium objects as soon as the `wait` condition returns an object with a `True` value, until a certain timeout. [See more on explicit waits in the documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/). You should make the appropriate condition for your case - maybe expecting a certain number of links is not good if you are not sure of how many links there will be in the end.
- Extracting what you want from the Selenium object. For that, use the appropriate method over the elements in the list you got from the step above.